# I don't understand what's wrong with this micro python

Tags: microcontroller, micropython, adc, servo

I've tested this script, and it works on independent servos, but when I add more, it stops working, is this something I'm being an idiot about? Or is there an actual problem?

I tried to assign the different potentiometers to control different servos, but it doesn't work with more than 1.

this is my code:

```
from machine import Pin, PWM, ADC
import utime

pot1 = ADC(Pin(28))
pot2 = ADC(Pin(27))
pot3 = ADC(Pin(26))
pot4 = ADC(Pin(22))

servo1 = PWM(Pin(1))
servo2 = PWM(Pin(2))
servo3 = PWM(Pin(3))
servo4 = PWM(Pin(4))

servo1.freq(50)
servo2.freq(50)
servo3.freq(50)
servo4.freq(50)


# A .duty_u16 value of c.1350 is zero degrees; 8200 is 180 degrees.
# This needs the calculation here for clarity! :)

while True:
    value1 = int(1350 + (pot1.read_u16()/9.57))
    servo1.duty_u16(value1)
    utime.sleep(0.02)

    value2 = int(1350 + (pot2.read_u16()/9.57))
    servo2.duty_u16(value2)
    utime.sleep(0.02)

    value3 = int(1350 + (pot3.read_u16()/9.57))
    servo3.duty_u16(value3)
    utime.sleep(0.02)
    
    value4 = int(1350 + (pot4.read_u16()/9.57))
    servo4.duty_u16(value4)
    utime.sleep(0.02)
```

(and yes, everything is hooked up correctly, that's the first thing I verified)

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but isn't the `duty` value supposed to vary between 0 and 1024? You don't mention what device you're using, but that seems true for the various ports for which I've checked the docs.

Comment: I'm on a raspberry pi pico, and the documentation I'm reading says 0 to 65535, can you point me to where you read that?

Comment: I was looking at the docs for the esp32 and esp8266, but now that we know what device you're using it's obvious that's not the problem. By "stops working", do you means that all the servos stop operating *at all*, or is something else happening?

Comment: Only the servo on servo1 and the potentiometer pot1 functions, nothing else is functional.

Comment: If you remove the _first_ servo instead of the _fourth_, do the others work again?